# What formula could I use for conditional formatting to highlight cells in Column B if the text in Column A has a link in it?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting

I want to easily see what text in Column A has a link in it by looking at Column B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply to range `B:B`

custom formula `=isurl(A1)`

If you want it to detect custom hyperlinks then you need to do something like this

```
=or(isurl(A1),iferror(search("hyperlink",formulatext(A1))))
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much!